# Explaining why the graph of $\cos(\sin x-\sin y)=\frac12$ looks the way it does

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I was playing around in Desmos, when I came across [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9ujxk7pd0d): $$\cos(\sin x-\sin y)=\frac12.$$

[image]

My goal was to come up with reasons for why an equation leads to a graph, but I was stuck on this one. I could not come up with a reasonable explanation for how this equation leads to weird rounded shapes across the plane. If someone could explain I would be grateful.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3837073

Comment: Part of the explanation is: if we shift either $x$ or $y$ by $2\pi$, then the value of $\cos(\sin x - \sin y)$ is preserved. This explains some of the periodicity. Furthermore, if we shift both $x$ and $y$ by $\pm \pi$, then $\sin x - \sin y$ switches signs and thus $\cos (\sin x - \sin y)$ is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

First visualize the 3D graphs of $f(x,y)=\sin x$ and $g(x,y)=-\sin y$. These graphs form "waves" in the $x$ direction and in the $y$ direction, respectively.

Now consider the 3D graph of their sum, $h(x,y)=f(x,y)+g(x,y)=\sin x-\sin y$. Adding the vertical and horizontal waves together gives us a regular pattern of smooth bumps. Also, since the $\sin$ function's range is $[-1,1]$, the values of $h$ lie in $[-2,2]$.

Now consider your equation, $\cos(\sin x-\sin y)=\frac12$. When $\theta\in[-2,2]$, the equation $\cos\theta=\frac12$ is equivalent to $\theta=\pm\alpha$, where $\alpha=\cos^{-1}\frac12=\frac\pi3\approx1.047$. (You can see this roughly by looking at the graph of the cosine function.) This means your equation is equivalent to $h(x,y)=\pm\alpha$.

In other words, your equation finds the places where the 3D graph of $h$ intersects the planes $z=\alpha$ and $z=-\alpha$. This amounts to a pattern of rings that encircle our (upward and downward) bumps.